# Why does this code snippet return False?

Tags: functions, function-construction, boolean-computation

```
f[_x] := x^2
g[_x] := x^2
TrueQ[f[x] == g[x]]
```

Can anyone explain why it returns False, while `TrueQ[x^2 == x^2]` does not? Does it compare the value of the pointers of the functions? How can I compare the "content" of defined functions otherwise?

Comment: I believe you meant to write these as `f[x_] := x^2`; what you have written is a function that matches on any pattern with the head x, such as x[] or x[1,2].  The symbol x itself has head Symbol, so f[x] is just f[x].

Comment: @user21382: your comment would make a perfectly valid answer i think, why not post it as an answer? :)

Comment: @user21382 is right, if you use the proper syntax it will return True.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you meant to write these as `f[x_] := x^2; g[x_] := x^2;`. What you have written is a pair of functions that match on any pattern with the head x (by using `_x` instead of `x_`), such as x[] or x[1,2]. The symbol x itself has head Symbol, so `f[x]` does not match `f[_x]`. See the page on [Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) for more information.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := x^2;
TrueQ[f[x] == g[x]]
```

> True